# What kind of hash encryption is this?

Tags: encryption, hash

Im trying to find out what kind of hash encryption this is in javascipt:

```
function L(j) {
    var h = a.pbkey,
        g = a.rndnb;
    if (typeof f != "undefined") {
        var e = f.PBK(h),
            d = f.STBUNC(j),
            i = f.STBA(g),
            c = f.ENC(d, e, i),
            b = f.BAT64(c);
        return b
    } else return ""
}
```

It hash a phonenumber.Ex: +79645531974

```
pbkey:'e=010001;m=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'
rndnb:'7fc1cdfea47d0057bbb33176ce73a376f9319d4e221d84807d74ff2f859b510b9fd132e577ed207d96b1d11e57500bff93efe97842248bcbe39527592797b7e3a821110ae61c3da67c2773bcb634c53357fb230ef95297d20c37d256aa8bd75bea315f2d
```

Result: `4LW/+zyiBBgDExOLPLafO9T/GG3guycSMK3uz16qFcXWgvo1KAF8VrbGrxAE91Mvk6qUDkX8c9ha7urDB41XDAhciBbj2VzE48WXjB/A6gI6n7qcTwkNTPT0Qly1EFRtTF44xTbPEld/OviYhD2OolumbtL42wtnyw1oh4/2v2SyAqARdGJizRhd1UFpWW+OUIcF3eyhKS1R+TDorsOoM/bJQzR6CTSyLysfPJL8ldjG0Ujevac7dT+WvaXFmP3qlsReMP/FSLjs7xixCAA/VrxIRUragoIOf2cptilop5zJNY26DO/iEhUUU7n8ANayrqthplS3v624XR24iM22bg==`

Comment: What is clear is that the code is **horrible**, meaningless single letter variables, cryptic function names. No clue as to `a` and `f`. The concept is to write code for other developers to read and easily understand, in that regard the code is a complete fail.

Comment: I think it may just be minified/uglyfied code. Perhaps this is more of a reverse engineering challenge?

Answer (score 1):

**The code *suggests* that it uses 2048 bit RSA encryption (with public exponent 65537) and a randomized padding scheme.**

But with only this code it is impossible to solve the whole thing. We need to know what the `PBK()`, `STBUNC()`, `STBA()`, `ENC()`, `BAT64()` functions do, otherwise we cannot definitively say *anything* about what is done here.

However, the input parameters give some suggestions. The **pbkey** parameter suggests that the encryption is "public-key" based and uses an exponent **e = 65537** (a commonly used RSA public exponent). Then it's an easy guess that **m** stands for "modulus". We could be dealing with either RSA or some logarithm-group crypto (e.g. ElGamal). To get more information we could check if this modulus `m` is a prime number, turns out it's not. So logarithm-group crypto is off the table and so we are *probably* dealing with [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). Notice how the modulus and the output are each 2048 bits, so this checks out.

But we're not done. We also have the **rndnb** value, which probably means "random number". This suggests that the encryption is not textbook RSA (thank god), but uses some kind of randomization. Possible it uses some kind of standard padding scheme like [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding).

To get more details we would really need to get the bodies of the functions that are use.